# Como soluciono un error en mi reproductor de musica en android NULL ARRAY

Tags: java, android

Estoy desarrollando un reproductor , la app en algunos dispositivos funciona pero en un celular reciente me arroja "Attemp to get lenght of null array" , alguien que me ayude? me marca error en el File archivos root.

````
       public  ArrayList<File> xd(File root){
       ArrayList<File> canciones= new ArrayList<File>();
       File[] archivos=root.listFiles();
       for (File lista: archivos)
       {
           if (lista.isDirectory() && !lista.isHidden())
           {
            canciones.addAll(xd(lista));
           }
           else{
               if(lista.getName().endsWith(".mp3") )
               {
                   canciones.add(lista);
               }
           }
       }

       return canciones;
   }```


el otro error es este 
```  File c = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
       final ArrayList<File> canciones=xd(new File(c.getAbsolutePath() ));```

aqui esta el error que aparece en el log cat , la linea 67 es la de " for (File lista: archivos)"   y la linea 34 lo del Environment
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyLL9.png
````

Comment: Hola! Podrías agregar lo que te manda el log, también que código tiene tu función llamada 'xd' y  cual es el directorio donde guardas los archivos que quieres cargar:)

Comment: @rguzman acabo de editar la publicacion con la foto